# approximation problem

Tags: approximation-theory, linear-approximation

We know that 30/3=10, 
therefore 30/3 could be written as 10×3/3=3.333.....×3=9.9999........ 
Which is approximately equal to 10 but not exactly 10.
Why this kind of approximation errors happen ?

Comment: So 10 is not exactly 10.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, 10 and 9.99999... are exactly the same number. This is the issue of the [non-uniqueness of decimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation#Non-uniqueness_of_decimal_representation_and_notational_conventions) of numbers.